# Feedback request: Linode for Magento hosting?

Tags: linode, magento

i install and customize a self made application for web pages which uses spring+jstl and the admin uses flex. Also i want to add to my offers an ecommerce cms, so i have decided to start with magento.

I'm using daily razor vps, however i was thinking in switching to linode because of the price. My questions are:

1.- Is linode good for magento ?
2.- is linode good for java+tomcat+jstl+mysql apps ?
3.- What are the most demanding resources to magento ? CPU ? RAM ? Does it consumes more if i have more products?

Well i hope to learn from you, this page is always so helpful

UPDATE: A final question:

4.- Do you recomend another vps service for my requieriments ?

Comment: Hi Ernest, have you tried Magento on Linode now? How is?

Comment: I've been a happy linode customer for over 10 years - LAMP, email, file storage, game servers, etc. If you find that you are resource limited too often, spend an extra $5/mo for the next level up of "hardware"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used magneto, but I do use several linode VPSs, and have found them to be excellent with powerful cpus and fast IO.

Linode prorates to the day, so you can easily get a server for a few days to do some testing and see if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Before migrating to Linode, I was using DigitalOcean for one of my client's Magento store via Cloudways, but I felt like the DigitalOcean server was unstable for me.

I thought that it was a problem with the data center, so I changed it from New York to San Francisco, but the results were the same.

So, I tried Vultr and Linode, and I think Linode is  the best option for me because the performance and the stability both seem to be a bit better with regards to the page load time and active users sessions.

I know Linode is more expensive than other cloud hosting services, but that doesn't justify switching back from Linode to anywhere else for me.

So as a Magento developer, I would suggest to at least try Linode by yourself and see how well it works for you.